# Want to convert the list of strings to map in java 8

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8

I am having a list of strings I need to put that in Map in the form of key,value pair in java 8.can someone help me.

```
List<string> list= [(Id=123,roll number=1,name=maddy)];
```

I need the values of id as key and value as 123.The same for all the items separated by commas.But I need it in java 8

Comment: Can you define the type of your `Map<K,V>`?

Comment: `list.stream().map(s -> s.split("=")).collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));`

Comment: "gimme the codez" question = 2 upvotes ... some people should not be able to vote at all.

Comment: I see that the question has been marked as a duplicate of some other question that asked for the exact opposite. Was that meant to be some kind of sarcasm?

Comment: I propose re-opening it as not a duplicate, and immediately re-closing it as no effort was shown to have been made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Split the elements of the `List` and collect to `Map`:

```
Map<String,String> map = 
    list.stream()
        .map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a->a[0], a->a[1]));
```

Note that if the key should be an `Integer`, you'll have to change `a[0]` to `Integer.valueOf(a[0])`.

Also note that if the `List` may contain duplicate keys, you should decide how to handle them (and possibly add a merge function to the collector).